# Need Header on Top and separator at section end for Horizontal UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I am implementing horizontal UICollectionView

I need a header on the Top and a separator at the end of section, where section > 0

[image]

Tried using flow layouts, having trouble of assigning different layout attribute for separator and header view depending on sections

Comment: Either make them all cells or else you will need to write a custom layout.